# Suitability of ArangoDB for heavily updated arrays / embedded documents

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

I'm investigating the suitability of ArangoDB for a specific use case:

1. I have a relatively high number of root documents.
2. Each document represents the top of a hierarchy.
3. The hierarchies are traversed as graphs.
4. The link between each level in the hierarchy is established via a combination of arrays of embedded documents and via IDs in arrays that point to documents.
5. I need to be able to push IDs onto & delete from arrays.
6. I need to be able to to add / remove embedded documents.

My questions:

1. Is ArangoDB able to update embedded documents without updating the entire container document?
2. Does it have a mechanism to address individual items in arrays for the purpose of pushing at item onto the end / deleting an item *in an efficient manner* (i.e. not degrading in speed at something like O(n).

I have looked in the documentation and searched online, but couldn't find clear answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) There is **no** in-place-updating of documents in ArangoDB. When updating a document, ArangoDB will store the new, updated of the original document. The new version is self-contained, meaning it contains the (updated) entire container. The old version of the document is still kept around because other currently running operations may reference it. Outdated versions of documents will eventually be deleted.

2) As can be seen in answer 1, pushing a value into an array or deleting a value from an array will build a new self-contained version of the entire document. That means pushing/deleting an array value will take as long as the construction of the entire document, as this is proportional to the size of the document (i.e. the more array values, the longer this will take).